# How to create a Pop up view in xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to create a Pop Up view that with an overlay.

I have tried with `Absolute Layout` to do this.

But I can not achieve navigation part here that should come from bottom to top.

This can be done in xamarin.iOS with `Modal Presentation`.

How can I do this in `xamarin Forms`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal

Comment: Xamarin.Forms provides support for modal pages as Jason mentioned in his comment. Create your custom-view and present it with modal style. Or you can write an animation to move the view from bottom to top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The popup animation is more like scaling from bottom than translation. (Check the Popup animation in the android default popups in settings page)

You can achieve the navigation like effect by setting Anchor and then animating Scale property of the popup view.

You can achieve any animation of popup using the built in Xamarin animation. I have provided an example of scale from bottom right here.

Xaml for popup

```
        <Frame
            x:Name="popuplayout"
            HasShadow="True"
            IsVisible="False"
            Scale="0"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,0.5,0.5">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="One"/>
                <Label Text="Two"/>
                <Label Text="Three"/>
                <Label Text="Four"/>
                <Label Text="Five"/>
                <Label Text="Six"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```

cs button click for the popup animation.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.popuplayout.IsVisible)
        {
            this.popuplayout.IsVisible = !this.popuplayout.IsVisible;
            this.popuplayout.AnchorX = 1;
            this.popuplayout.AnchorY = 1;

            Animation scaleAnimation = new Animation(
                f => this.popuplayout.Scale = f,
                0.5,
                1,
                Easing.SinInOut);

            Animation fadeAnimation = new Animation(
                f => this.popuplayout.Opacity = f,
                0.2,
                1,
                Easing.SinInOut);

            scaleAnimation.Commit(this.popuplayout, "popupScaleAnimation", 250);
            fadeAnimation.Commit(this.popuplayout, "popupFadeAnimation", 250);
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.WhenAny<bool>
              (
                this.popuplayout.FadeTo(0, 200, Easing.SinInOut)
              );

            this.popuplayout.IsVisible = !this.popuplayout.IsVisible;
        }
```

Above code UI result.

[image]

Hope this could help you in achieving your UI.

Comment: The gif file animation is very slower than the real animation due to conversion from mov file

Comment: Very happy that I could help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Rg.Plugins.Popup** for creating wonderful  popups in xamarin.forms.
Refer here https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

For more details https://askxammy.com/how-to-work-with-advanced-pop-ups-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: this is really useful, Thanks.

but is there any way to we can do this without using a plugin?

Comment: did you checked this https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-custom-popup

Answer (score 0):

```
           //  Install Rg.Plugins.Popup Nuget Package

           //xaml code view for popup

           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <animations:PopupPage  xmlns:animations="http://rotorgames.com" 
       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App.Modules.EmployeeTestDescriptionPopupPage"
                    xmlns:customControl="clr- 
           namespace:App.Controls">
         <Frame VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10,0,10,0" 
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
    <StackLayout >
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#09326A" 
           Padding="10,10,10,10">

            <Label Text="Display Description"  TextColor="White" FontSize="20" > 
           </Label>
            <Image HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="40,0,0,0">
                <Image.Source>
                    <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf00d;"
                                     Size="20"
                                     Color="White"
                                     FontFamily="{StaticResource 
          FontAwesomeSolid}"></FontImageSource>
                </Image.Source>
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ClosePopup_Tapped" 
           NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="lblDescription" FontSize="14"/> 
              **//Body of popup will come here**
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <!--Buttons Start-->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <Button Text="Close" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#F46A6A" 
    Clicked="ClosePopup_Tapped"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <!--Buttons End-->
    </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
           </animations:PopupPage>


         // xaml.cs code


            using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
         using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
      using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;

             using Xamarin.Forms;
             using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

           namespace App.Modules
             {
       [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class EmployeeTestDescriptionPopupPage : 
           PopupPage
             {
             public EmployeeTestDescriptionPopupPage(string 
                         TestDescription)
               {

        InitializeComponent();
        lblDescription.Text = TestDescription;

    }

    //Close Button Functionality
    public async void ClosePopup_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
    }
    }
      }
```