# Is there a way to animate the width of button programmatically from both sides

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to be able to resize animatedly the button from both sides for now I was able to do it from one side right to left.

Code ->

```cs
double Height = Button1.Height;
bool x = await Button1.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(new Point(Button1.X, Button1.Y), new Size(150, Height)), 1200,Easing.Linear);
```

Button ->

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Row="0" Clicked="Button1_Clicked" BorderRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="1500" />
            <!--<ActivityIndicator Grid.Row="1" IsRunning="true" ></ActivityIndicator>-->
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

(Before animation) ->

[image]

(After animation) ->

[image: ![](https://i.imgur.com/yFGbAq0.png?1)]

(I want) ->

[image: ![](https://i.imgur.com/eLfO6Rt.png?1)]

Comment: Have you tried CenterAndExpand the horizontal options for the button?

Comment: Yes, didn't help tho

Comment: Would you share more about the layout hierarchy that contains this button?

Comment: Yeah, (Updated).

Comment: And have you tried with the Parent StackLayout with FillAndExpand? with the Grid inside with Center?

Comment: i think for better understanding of what's going on, you should add temporary vibrant background colors to the Stack and Grid layouts, to see what is not centered

Comment: Before animation: https://imgur.com/jKKrHur
After:https://imgur.com/eV2J6jr
Blue background, yellow button, red grid

Comment: okey, much clear, so it isn't about the layout itself but the problem relies on the LayoutTo Method, i found this article: http://xfcomplete.net/xamarin.forms/2016/01/14/layoutto-doesnt-do-what-you-think-it-does/ i hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Resize is all you intend to do, use `ScaleXTo` with `AnchorX` set to 0.5(default).

Set AnchorX in XAMl:

```
<Button
    x:Name="Button1"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Clicked="Button1_Clicked"
    BorderRadius="20"
    AnchorX="0.5"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    WidthRequest="1500" />
```

Use [ScaleXTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple) in cs

```
void Button1_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (Button1.ScaleX < 1)
    {
        Button1.ScaleXTo(1);
    }
    else
    {
        Button1.ScaleXTo(0.5);
    }
}
```

Give it a whirl and comment if further info is needed. Hope it helps.

Comment: Button does not contain a definition for 'ScaleXTo' and no accessible extensions method 'ScaleXTo' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found.

Comment: May I know the Xamarin forms version? If possible upgrade your Xamarin forms. I'll update the UI result please check if this is what you require

Comment: Oh, sorry my version of Xamarin on test bench was 4.3, it was what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy that it helped you :). Moreover if ScaleXTo is not available you can you Animate of Xamarin Forms to animate any property of VisualElement. Check out the answer by me in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259724/how-to-create-a-pop-up-view-in-xamarin-forms/59261271#59261271).

Answer (score 0):

After reading about LayoutTo method i found this [Article](http://xfcomplete.net/xamarin.forms/2016/01/14/layoutto-doesnt-do-what-you-think-it-does/)

Quoting:

> First what it is meant for. LayoutTo is actually used cause a child to
>   be layed out in a series of animated steps to a new location. This
>   sounds useful but there are a couple important things to note.
>
> - It was only intended to be used by Xamarin.Forms.Layout subclasses,
>        not externally.
> - It is stupidly exposed in the same way the other
>        animation methods are.
> - It will initially appear to do what you want,
>        but anything that triggers a relayout will cause your views position
>        to reset to where it started.

So i'm guessing that LayoutTo doesn't take take in acount the LayoutOptions for that element, so a better solution would be using other animation methods like `TranslateTo` or [Animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.animation.-ctor?view=xamarin-forms)

Comment: The point of this is not to move the button, the point is to resize it.

Comment: @Cursed i think you can still resize the button using other animation methods, and i'm sure with Animation you can do that, i'm sorry but i can't add an example of a working animation with resizing right now, but i will  add to my anwser once i have it, i edited my anwser to include animation methods too

Comment: @Cursed just cameback to this question, and it seems someone already has anwsered the way i was going to do it, check it