# How to cut the width of a button from both sides using winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, resize, width

Is there a way to cut the width of a button from both sides?

For example if I cut the width of the button by 300 by default it will cut right to left but I want to do -150 from the left and -150 from the right.

What I am trying to accomplish is greatly described in the link below but the solution doesn't work for me.

[Is there a way to animate the width of button programmatically from both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100499/is-there-a-way-to-animate-the-width-of-button-programmatically-from-both-sides)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I get this right, you want to subtract half from the `Width` and add the other half to the `Left` property.

```
int x = 300;
button.Width -= x / 2;
button.Left += x / 2;
```