# Xamarin Forms Page Transition Animation

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to animate my page so that when the settings icon(in the top right) is clicked, the settings page will expand from the top right as a circle over the current main page.[Example settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qOXe.png)

Also when you click on the corner of the mainpage I want to close the circle.
Does anyone have any idea of how I could do this?

Comment: HI, Can you go through this link? Maybe it will help to some extend

Comment: https://github.com/GiampaoloGabba/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my question here: [Popout frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259724/how-to-create-a-pop-up-view-in-xamarin-forms)

I created a frame with a corner radius such that the frame was a circle shape then I used a scale animation to make it pop in and out.