# Xamarin.Forms: How to Programmatically Open a Popup Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, stack, popupwindow, back

In my app, on initializing a page (let's call it `FirstPage`) I check for some conditions and, if necessary, want to display a warning page (let's call it `WarningPage`). The content of this page will be too complicated for Alert Boxes - with links and some formatting.

I tried to call `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("WarningPage");` but I did not find the appropriate moment to do this. If called in `OnAppearing()`, `WarningPage` shows up **after** I close `MainPage`.

What I want is that the navigation stack contains `FirstPage` -> `WarningPage` -> (perhaps a third page by clicking on a link in `WarningPage`) and he gets back to `FirstPage` when he closes the `WarningPage`.

**Edit:** No errors occur in MainPage but `WarningPage` shows up **after** I close `MainPage`.

Comment: what specifically is the problem with using `OnAppearing`?

Comment: The page ist not completely loaded, I get some unspecific errors in `FirstPage` that obviously occurred because this page had not yet finished loading. Some weeks ago I had a similar problem that I could solve otherwise.

Comment: Why does that matter?  What **specific** problem does that cause?  What are `unspecific errors`?

Comment: Ok, I try to reproduce these errors. It'll take some minutes...

Comment: See my **Edit**

Comment: Your code or minimum repo plz

Comment: You can accept your own answer. This may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I *seemed* to solve it, but not for all cases: I use the `Appearing` event in `FirstPage`:

```
    public FirstPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Appearing += FirstPage_Appearing;
    }
```

In this event I use`Navigation.PushModalAsync`:

```
    private void FirstPage_Appearing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new WarningPage());
    }
```

This does what I want but not really:

This works only for one of my pages, unfortunately not for the page where I actually need this feature. So - who can tell me a way that always works to programmatrically switch from one page to a second one and allow to use the Back function to go back to the first page?

When I have time, I'll try to find out under what circumstances it works and what I have to do otherwise.

Comment: I changed the title to **Xamarin.Forms: How to Programmatically Open a Popup Page**

Answer (score 0):

it is not completely what I indended but I can live with a solution as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259724/how-to-create-a-pop-up-view-in-xamarin-forms#answer-59261271).

Now the next question arises: In my solution the rest of the page is shifted down. I would like to have covered the remaining page by this popup.

This will be the next question in ths forum.